# Omniauth-Twitter - original profile image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, omniauth

I am using [Omniauth-Twitter gem](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter.git) to authenticate users and show their profile images. When I attempt to display a full-size user profile image in my `users#show` view, via `link_to` method, the image gets resized to 41x41px. Is there any way to get a standard image URL (256x256px)?

My `omniauth.rb` initializer has the default image size set to `original`, as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, "...", "..."
    {
        ...

        :secure_image_url => 'true',
        :image_size => 'original',

        ...
    }
end
```

and my `User` model appends the Twitter image URL to a column in the `Users` table like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            ...
            user.image_url = auth.info.image
            ...
        end

    end

end
```

What I've tried:

1. Removing `:image_size` pair from the data hash
2. Passing `width:` and `height:` properties to the `link_to`
3. Changing the value of the `image_size` key to
   `.extra.raw_info.profile_image_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found would probably violate the mighty **convention over configuration** principle:

remove any calls that determine the image size (i.e. from the URL string by using `.gsub!` method like so:

```
"profile_image_path_normal.jpg".gsub!("_normal","") #replaces "_normal" with nothing
```

Would love to hear other suggestions.